# Problems with correct display after rotation

Tags: iphone, html

I developed the page www.projekt-meine-zukunft.at Now the problem is that if I load the page in my iPhone in portrait-mode and rotate the page to landscape mode afterwards, the upper area of my page is not shown.
On the other hand, if I load the page in landscape mode, the whole page is displayed.

I have no idea what the reason for this could be.

Any hints are welcome :)

Thanks in advance,

enne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with scaling of the viewport in the different orientations.  You can see a fix for this issue here:

http://www.blog.highub.com/mobile-2/a-fix-for-iphone-viewport-scale-bug/

Comment: Well I have already implemented this script but with the same result.